# Which version of CodeIgniter am I currently using?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Quick question.

Is there something similar to a **`phpinfo()`** - that would display the version for **`CodeIgniter`**?

Thanks.

Comment: Is CodeIgniter still used widely in php?

Comment: @Timo [not really](https://trends.google.com.ar/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=codeigniter,laravel,symphony), although there's version 3 now. This was asked in '10 though, CI has seen more use in those times.

Comment: Actually it is well mantained, it is still a good option for ligth weigth framework users.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Yes, the [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) `CI_VERSION` will give you the current CodeIgniter version number. <del>It's defined in: /system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php</del> As of CodeIgniter 2, it's defined in /system/core/CodeIgniter.php

For example,

```
echo CI_VERSION; // echoes something like 1.7.1
```

Comment: Correct. It's also in the commments of that file though, so no need to write or run code just to find out the version.

Comment: In newer versions CodeIgniter.php is located in /system/core folder.

Comment: @downvoter: Why the recent downvote on this answer? Is something incorrect?

Comment: Downvote because @Timo's answer is much more precise and this answer does not make any sense; why use a function to *echo* a constant when one could either just use the constant or echo it from a view or whereever it is needed?

Comment: @ThomasDaugaard: A downvote implies the answer is not helpful. While I agree that the `get_version` wrapper is superfluous, the fact that I pointed out that this constant exists does answer the question and, I would argue, *is* helpful. Your point is taken, however, and I've edited to remove the `get_version` wrapper. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @ThomasDaugaard yea, this is the best answer i think. no need to be downvoted

Comment: If you are in linux, go to the directory where code igniter is installed and use the command `grep -ir "ci_version" ./`

Answer (score 125):

Look for `define` in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`:

```
define('CI_VERSION', '3.1.8');
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted and popular answer. Who wants to run a php file/function to get it to spit out what's written right there?

Comment: @TylerCollier Because thats what the question is, It asks if there is an option to spit out? I bet you read the question again before posting.

Comment: You're right! I didn't think of 'spit out' in that sense, but I'm sure some people want to get to it programmatically.

Comment: You can find the file using 'locate CodeIgniter.php' and then cat file | grep -i version

Comment: In Codeigniter 4, the CI_VERSION is defined in `system/CodeIgniter.php`. Look for it in `vendor/codeigniter4/framework/…`

Answer (score 15):

You should try :

```
<?php
echo CI_VERSION;
?>
```

Or check the file `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`

Answer (score 6):

you can easily find the current CodeIgniter version by

```
echo CI_VERSION 


or you can navigate to System->core->codeigniter.php file and you can see the constant

/**
 * CodeIgniter Version
 *
 * @var string
 *
 */
    const CI_VERSION = '3.1.6';
```

Answer (score 5):

From a controller or view - use the following to display the version:

```
<?php
   echo CI_VERSION;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check the file "system/core/CodeIgniter.php". It is defined in `const CI_VERSION = '3.1.10';`

Answer (score 3):

For CodeIgniter 4, use the following:

```
<?php    
    echo \CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION;
?>
```