# how can i find the version of codeigniter an application was written in?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm reviewing someone's code and I can see that they're using codeigniter.  But I'm trying to figure out which version they've used.  I've been rooting around in the directory structure to find some information but haven't been successful yet.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which version of CodeIgniter am I currently using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196799/which-version-of-codeigniter-am-i-currently-using)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside the framework, it's defined in 'CI_VERSION'.

Path is system/core/CodeIgniter.php

```
define('CI_VERSION', '2.1.3');
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple as this;

```
echo CI_VERSION;
```

The constant is globally available and is pre-filled with the release version of the code you have.

Just put the echo in an empty controller and call it in the browser to test it.