# how to check version of codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently setup a old Codeigniter framework on my xampp.But i don't know the version of this framework.
 I use the code

```
<?php echo CI_VERSION; ?>
```

but its give me error

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CI_VERSION - assumed 'CI_VERSION' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projectname/views/v_header.php on line 57
CI_VERSION
```

Please guide me, I am new in Codeigniter.

Comment: '<?php echo CI_VERSION; ?>' should echo out the correct version of CI. if it doesn't something might be wrong with your CI installation - specially if you comment several times that you have no system folder! I would try to re-install CI from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which version of CodeIgniter am I currently using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196799/which-version-of-codeigniter-am-i-currently-using)

Answer (score 41):

See in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` and there is a constant like  this..

```
define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.6');
```

Comment: I have no any folder with name of system

Comment: see in root directory.

Answer (score 13):

In the root folder:

```sh
cat system/core/CodeIgniter.php | grep CI_VERSION
```

Comment: UUOC: `grep CI_VERSION system/core/CodeIgniter.php`

Answer (score 10):

You can check it two ways. one is to

```
<?php echo CI_VERSION; ?>
```

Another way is go to your **system/core/CodeIgniter.php** path and then check `define('CI_VERSION', '2.1.4');`

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1:**

Please access the file

> System >> Core >> Codeigniter.php

```
 /**
  * CodeIgniter Version
  *
  * @var    string
  *
  */
  define('CI_VERSION', '3.0.0');
```

**Method 2:**
In index.php or any other view file write the following code of php as follows:

```
 <?php
   echo CI_VERSION;
 ?>
```

CI_VERSION is build in constant in codeigniter, which contains value of version.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

check the file system/core/CodeIgniter.php

Comment: I have no any folder with name of system

Comment: There are 3 folders in your root folder. They are 'application','system' and 'user guides'.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:`<?php echo CI_VERSION; ?> // echoes something like 3.1.6`

Answer (score 2):

Which means you are not properly configure your codeigniter project / system folder. System folder is not necessary to be placed in project root. you can place anywhere and configure the correct system path[something like `$system_path = '../system';`] in the index.php(project root) properly. It should work...

Answer (score 2):

If you are running CodeIgniter 4, the CodeIgniter 3 style

```
<?php echo CI_VERSION; ?>
```

would not work out and you would get the error - Use of undefined constant CI_VERSION

As @user1283182 has pointed out, the exact version can be found in system/CodeIgniter.php (see **const CI_VERSION**)

or enter the below code in one of your views

```
<?= CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For CodeIgniter 4, the CI_VERSION is defined in system\CodeIgniter.php

Answer (score 1):

Just use this simple code to check for Codeigniter version

```
<?= CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For CodeIgniter 4

You can also try following path to find CodeIgniter version.

D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php

In CodeIgniter.php file, find the following line;

public const CI_VERSION = '4.3.3';

Comment: Hi, please note, your answer is specific to Windows systems