# How to recognize the CodeIgniter version of a php source?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to recognize the CodeIgniter version of a php source?

```
/**<br>
 * CodeIgniter<br>
 *<br>
 * An open source application development framework for PHP<br>
 *<br>
 * This content is released under the MIT License (MIT)<br>
 *<br>
 * Copyright (c) 2014 - 2016, British Columbia Institute of Technology<br>
 *<br>
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy<br>
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal<br>
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights<br>
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell<br>
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is<br>
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:<br>
 *<br>
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in<br>
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.<br>
 *<br>
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.<br>
 *<br>
 * @package CodeIgniter<br>
 * @author  EllisLab Dev Team<br>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc. (https://ellislab.com/)<br>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 - 2016, British Columbia Institute of Technology (http://bcit.ca/)<br>
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT  MIT License<br>
 * @link    https://codeigniter.com<br>
 * @since   Version 1.0.0  <---- THIS IS THE VERSION or WHAT??<br>
 * @filesource<br>
 */
```

Thankyou very match!

Comment: Please don't tag-spam with all CodeIgniter tags.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which version of CodeIgniter am I currently using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196799/which-version-of-codeigniter-am-i-currently-using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For see codeigniter version, you have to write this code

```
 <?php
      echo CI_VERSION;
 ?>
```

Or you can check the file `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`

Answer (score 2):

There is a constant defined that determines the version in `/system/core/Codeigniter.php`

```
define('CI_VERSION', 'x.xx')
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `Codeigniter` is defined in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`.

You can get the current version using:

```
echo CI_VERSION;//outputs your current CI's version
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Check codeigniter version, you have to write this code**

```
 <?php
      echo CI_VERSION;
 ?>
```

Or you can check the file `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` For version 3.xx

And
check the file `system/CodeIgniter.php` For version 4.xx